# Social share with Worklight

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, socialshare

I'm developing an app using Worklight and AngularJS, there is a necessity in this app with main objective to share certain text. 
My idea is to invoke the native method of sharing each operating system without restricting any application and use what is available in the operating system (start to Android and iOS). 
I would like to know if there are specific methods to invoke this routine using the Worklight or, if don't have, what the best practices to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worklight does not provide API to do so, but you can writing a Cordova plug-in that will invoke native code for each required platform, and will display the appropriate sharing sheet (for iOS) or share action (for Android).

To develop Cordova plug-ins for Worklight, follow the training modules:

- [Adding native functionality to hybrid applications with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid)

To invoke the native code, find the native code to do so. For example:

- [Social action sheet (like on iOS 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287007/social-action-sheet-like-on-ios-6)
- http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: After making  the reading of PDF Cordova module in training, I found  PhoneGap Social Sharing plugin [link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) with these it was possible to call the screen sharing options.