# Swift: share mp3 file via whatsapp

Tags: xcode, swift, whatsapp

I try to share a audio file from my app via whatsapp, but xcode shows a error:

```
var controller      = UIDocumentInteractionController()

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"whatsapp://app")!) {

        var savePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType:"mp3")

        controller          = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath:savePath!)!)
        controller.UTI      = "net.whatsapp.audio"
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)

    } else {
       println("error")
    }
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer _openDocumentWithApplication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17417c980'

Comment: Try making controller a member variable of the class this code is running is rather than a local variable

Comment: Take a look here may it helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077551/4538084