# Share text string using expo-sharing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, file-sharing

I'm trying to use Share dialog to share a piece of text on Expo. Though from the current [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/) I cannot find anything related to this.

Right now, my workaround is saving the text as .txt to user's device and sharing that. But surely there must be a better way-- even iOS has a [native way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320588/15916361). But how do I implement something similar with Expo's `expo-sharing` package?

My current workaround (modified for brevity):

```
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

...


  const shareText = async (text) => {
    if (!await Sharing.isAvailableAsync()) {
        alert("Sharing is not available on this platform");
        return;
    }

    const fileName = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "text"+new Date().getDate()+"-"+new Date().getMonth()+"-"+new Date().getFullYear()+"_"+new Date().getHours()+"-"+new Date().getMinutes()+".txt";
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileName, text);

    try {
        await Sharing.shareAsync(fileName);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed sharing: ", error.message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Its possible using React Native `share`. Works fine in Expo.

```
import { Share } from 'react-native';

...

const shareText = async (text) => {
    try {
        await Share.share({
            message: text
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sharing:', error);
    }
};
```